# Compile the Python interpreter for embedded linux

Tags: python, linux, embedded-linux

i'm trying to build a Linux distro and i need python in it.so far i compiled everything i needed with sharde library option and copy its binary and its needed library in my distro and they are working.i compiled python with this option:

```
./configure --prefix="/" --enable-shared
make
```

and copied binary and Lib directory in my distro.it will run but i got error when i'm importing standard libraries such as socket.

```
>>> import socket
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/lib/Lib/socket.py", line 47, in <module>
import _socket
ImportError: No module named _socket
```

I checked lib directory and socket.py is in there.
my purpose is to build a light embedded linux.compiling and and installing need so many tools and i cant just have all of them in my target.
I would appreciate if someone can help me.thank you in advanced and sorry for my English.

Comment: maybe i wasn't clear.i'm building a custom linux distro based on LFS.so i should compile application on my development linux and copy it to my custom linux

Comment: Does what you build work on the development linix system, but not on the one with the custom linix?

Comment: yes.but i think my compiled python use python's librareis that are pre installed in my linux(ubuntu) rather than using library that i compiled

Comment: In that case it sounds like the problem isn't with the build, instead that it's due to fact that you're trying to run an uninstalled interpreter. I don't know all the details, but an installed interpreter looks in several places (directories) when importing modules. At least one of those is the [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable. Try manually setting it to where the `_socket.so` (or `.pyd`) file is and see what happens.

Comment: You're welcome. I think something like this would apply to any uninstalled Python interpreter.

Comment: You don't need Python for a bootable LFS (AFAIK) -  is there any reason you want to install it from a chroot-environment? Is it booting already? Have u read the docs (http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/python2.html)?